# Printing output in the form of multiple sublist within a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am appending all the values to list `sigma_t` using the loop below. However, I want the values to be within a sublist for each `t`. I present the current and expected output.

```
import numpy as np
sigma0=0.021
R=8.314
T=295
K=1.5e3
Cb=0.001
km=[1,2,3,4,5]
threshold_sigma=0.005

sigma_t=[]
alpha_t=[]
for t in range(0,2): 
    for i in range(0,len(km)): 
        sigma1=sigma0-R*T*0.001*np.log(1+K*Cb*(1-np.exp(-km[i]*t)))
        if sigma1 < threshold_sigma:
            sigma1 = threshold_sigma
            
        sigma_t.append(sigma1)
    
        
print(sigma_t)
```

The current output is

```
[0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005]
```

The expected output is

```
[[0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021], [0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending values to sigma_t list inside your 2nd for loop, and then at the end of your code you're printing sigma_t. Hence you have all values sitting inside one list sigma_t.

For output to match the expected output, create an intermediate list, insert data in that list, and after you're done executing first for loop, insert that intermediate list in sigma_t and clear the intermediate list.

Something like this

```
for t in range(0,2):
    temp_list = []
    for i in range(0,len(km)): 
        sigma1=sigma0-R*T*0.001*np.log(1+K*Cb*(1-np.exp(-km[i]*t)))
        if sigma1 < threshold_sigma:
            sigma1 = threshold_sigma
            
        temp_list.append(sigma1)
    sigma_t.append(temp_list)
    
        
print(sigma_t)
```